# Parallel arrays in a loop function

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on an assignment and it's meant to take the concept of a car body shop offering different trim packages at different prices, the program is meant to use a pretest loop to stop the function if a user inputs a code that isn't already on the array, and then the user inputs the base price of their car and the program is meant to add the base price, the trim price and a 15% sales tax and give the new user their total cost. If I only had to create a function that displayed array's I think I'd have no trouble but I'm currently tearing my hair out trying to wrap my head around how to get all the different functions to work together

```
 currently my algorithm is 
    1)enter the base price of car

    2.) Enter the trim package code

    3.) searchIndex=0 
    while OptionPackageCodeArray =[search index]
        searchIndex++
    end loop

       if searchIndex<5
    input packageCode
    OptionPackageCode[searchIndex] = packageCode
  else
    Display error "This code does not exist"
    end if

    4.) Determine totalCost
    PackageCostArray[searchIndex] + basePrice = costwithPackage
    totalCost = costwithPackage*0.15

    5.) display total cost 
    "The price of your car with Trim is" : totalCost
     end loop
```

and the actual C++ I have written so far is

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
     {

    //declare variables
    double basePrice = 0.00;
    string OptionPackageCodeArray[] = {"BB", "SP", "NP", "HE", "UC"};
    double PackageCostArray [] = {1500.00, 3250.00, 4575.00, 7500.00, 5220.00};
    double totalCost = 0.00

    //prompt for base price
    cout << "Enter base price:"; 
    cin>>basePrice;

    cout <<"enter package code: BB, SP, NP, HE, UC";
    cin >> OptionPackageCodeArray;
         }
```

however I'm stuck at this point 
if anybody has any suggestions I'd be happy to take them.

Comment: "I'm stuck" covers a lot of ground.  Can you be more specific?  What exactly do you not know how to do?

Comment: Mostly on how to get the loop to parse out the letter code's that arent in the array and deliver an error message when an incorrect code is given

Answer (score 1):

you just write the code step by step. you can read blow code for reference.

```
  double basePrice = 0.00;
    static const int num = 5;
    string OptionPackageCodeArray[num] = {"BB", "SP", "NP", "HE", "UC"};
    double PackageCostArray [num] = {1500.00, 3250.00, 4575.00, 7500.00, 5220.00};
    double totalCost = 0.00;
    while(true)
    {   
        //prompt for base price
        cout << "Enter base price:"; 
        cin>>basePrice;
        std::string package;
        cout <<"enter package code: BB, SP, NP, HE, UC"<<std::endl;
        cin >> package;
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < num; i++)
        {   
            if (OptionPackageCodeArray[i] == package)
            {   
                break;
            }   
        }   
        if (i == num)
        {   
            break;
        }   
        else
        {   
            std::cout<<(basePrice + PackageCostArray[i]) * 0.15<<std::endl;
        }   

    }
```